# Deleting an object based on its value

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of objects as seen below:

```
obj = { 'epbv6IzBo00:APA91bHL_VOzupgrjpKHYh3SBjKUObfDcoHeQq5sFwXi1q6-Wl5qashhvN_tEqcie7y9wQjwSSOn9DiMjryjbXOjrSG69OlmE7KIziOebqCNTyTHfRzVKOv3iD7RospRLDVOYl-vnjEW': '00003',
    'fPCcX94Npbk:APA91bHQzzKUjzdAJaRvwzYLhm08NfgHX0_udV9mqPaEF3xklZ6KHgxOPf-eGtizfE8odfVJ93qyfAUDSoHQav-mieLIzUe_IIev-MfesIhudueBrCWj5BXIje7qmSCwwdrTKD6Wl3Vm': '00001' }
```

I am trying to loop through each key and find out if its value is equal to '00001'. If it is not equal to '00001' I want to delete that object from the collection. So in this example the output would be:

```
{ 'epbv6IzBo00:APA91bHL_VOzupgrjpKHYh3SBjKUObfDcoHeQq5sFwXi1q6-Wl5qashhvN_tEqcie7y9wQjwSSOn9DiMjryjbXOjrSG69OlmE7KIziOebqCNTyTHfRzVKOv3iD7RospRLDVOYl-vnjEW': '00001'}
```

The code I have now is below:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach( function (key) { //loop over the keys
     if (obj[key] =! "00001") {      //compare the name
        delete obj[key];                   //remove the entry
     }
});
console.log(obj);
```

But it outputs this instead for some reason:

```
{ 'epbv6IzBo00:APA91bHL_VOzupgrjpKHYh3SBjKUObfDcoHeQq5sFwXi1q6-Wl5qashhvN_tEqcie7y9wQjwSSOn9DiMjryjbXOjrSG69OlmE7KIziOebqCNTyTHfRzVKOv3iD7RospRLDVOYl-vnjEW': false,
'fPCcX94Npbk:APA91bHQzzKUjzdAJaRvwzYLhm08NfgHX0_udV9mqPaEF3xklZ6KHgxOPf-eGtizfE8odfVJ93qyfAUDSoHQav-mieLIzUe_IIev-MfesIhudueBrCWj5BXIje7qmSCwwdrTKD6Wl3Vm': false }
```

Comment: `=!` is not the same as `!=`. There is no comparison happening in your `if` condition.

Comment: I made the edit

Comment: `=!` is assigning to `obj[key]` the value of `!"0001"`, which in JavaScript is `false`. use the `!==` (not equal to) operator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this code

```
let obj = { 'epbv6IzBo00:APA91bHL_VOzupgrjpKHYh3SBjKUObfDcoHeQq5sFwXi1q6-Wl5qashhvN_tEqcie7y9wQjwSSOn9DiMjryjbXOjrSG69OlmE7KIziOebqCNTyTHfRzVKOv3iD7RospRLDVOYl-vnjEW': '00003',
    'fPCcX94Npbk:APA91bHQzzKUjzdAJaRvwzYLhm08NfgHX0_udV9mqPaEF3xklZ6KHgxOPf-eGtizfE8odfVJ93qyfAUDSoHQav-mieLIzUe_IIev-MfesIhudueBrCWj5BXIje7qmSCwwdrTKD6Wl3Vm': '00001' }


Object.keys(obj).forEach( function (key) { //loop over the keys
     if (obj[key] != "00001") {      //compare the name
        delete obj[key];                   //remove the entry
     }
});
console.log(obj);
```

Outputs

```
{fPCcX94Npbk:APA91bHQzzKUjzdAJaRvwzYLhm08NfgHX0_udV9mqPaEF3xklZ6KHgxOPf-eGtizfE8odfVJ93qyfAUDSoHQav-mieLIzUe_IIev-MfesIhudueBrCWj5BXIje7qmSCwwdrTKD6Wl3Vm: "00001"}
```

All you needed was to change `=!` to `!=`.

Answer (score -1):

```
(obj[key] =! "00001")
```

Syntax is not correct. It should be like

```
(obj[key] !== "00001")
```

Comment: it's more of javascript's leniency for syntax. =! it treats as assignment and negation of what comes right to bang sign. For comparison it does not make sense. Sebastian, do you think down vote is appropriate for such thing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with “leniency for syntax”. _“For comparison it does not make sense”_ — that’s why it’s semantically incorrect.